# How to count and display each impressions on ads in my android app?

Tags: android

I am making an Android App, in which I want to display the number of clicks on the ads showing in my app.

Please help me out in this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It would be nice to add some code of your android application, related to ads.

Comment: What kind of help are you looking for? What have you already done? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

If you will end up using AdMob (with Firebase or not it's the same), you can listen for `onAdOpened()` event, which means the user has triggered your ad in some way, like tapping on it. Inside that you could increase your click counter and update a TextView with the new value

You can find more info on this here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/ad-events#onadopened

Comment: Thank you MatPag, I am beginner so,can you please help me by posting the code.

Comment: Sorry but you should try to learn the basics before. StackOverFlow is meant to be an help during some specific trouble encountered while working on something. Nobody will provide you a solution from A to Z.

Comment: onAdImpression() does not work for adaptive banner ads right?